# Problemas em fazer acontecer eventos no JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou aprendendo sobre `events` no JavaSCript, e começei a praticar, porém me deparei com uma lógica que não estou conseguindo raciocinar ou associar.
Estou querendo que toda vez que eu clicar no botão, o nome dele seja mudado, no exemplo que está em comentário, esse funciona perfeitamente, claro que lá no primeiro *modelo* `HTML` o `button` não tem o `onclick`, mas no segundo *modelo* em que eu coloco o `onclick: "myFunction()"`, e faço a função no .js, dá um **Uncaght TypeError**. Eu não estou conseguindo entender por o nome do `button` não muda

> Eu acho que tem alguma coisa haver com os parênteses no `onclick: "myFunction()"`, sendo isso ou não, não sei o que está havendo

```
HTML
    <div class="container">
        <section class="container-left">
            <h1>Easy Shopping Via Mobile</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lorem justo, sollicitudin vel ultricies
                sed,
                eleifend nec metus. Etiam vitae pellentesque dolor. </p>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Started</button>
        </section>
```

```
JS
const element = document.querySelector("button")

// element.onclick = function () {
//     element.innerHTML = "Hokage"
//  }

const myFunction = (element) => {
    element.innerHTML = "Hokage"
}
```

Comment: Na arrow function foi declarada  um parametro 'element´   .. que poderia ser apenas parametro vazio na arrow  `() =>`  .... esse parametro não faz relação ao `const element = do....`  é uma declaração a função sem relação ao button... portanto para fazer a ação usa o **this**.. refere se ao objeto que está executando a função atual... no html no parametro da função chamada usa o **this**

Comment: Poderia declarar qualquer nome dentro do parametro da arrow que não tera relação a declaração a declaração do button... poderia até ser `const myFunction = (batataFrita) => {
    batataFrita.innerHTML = "Hokage"
}`    .... mas na chamada dentro do button no html devera ter o **this**

Comment: e a variavel  `element`  podera ser excluida,,, ja que diretamente esta usando `onclick=` no html e não como no código anterior que si manter comentado.

Answer (score -1):

Ola, seu erro esta no seu evento onclick, a função myFunction recebe um objeto, myFunction(Objeto), porém no seu evento onclick está apenas myFunction(). O correto seria:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Get Started</button>
```

Comment: esse this é um nome específico para essa ocasião na linguagem de programação ou uma palavra qualquer?